# Twilio function giving invalid content-type error

Tags: twilio, content-type

I'm trying to make an outgoing call to an automated phone system, but I'm running into a content-type error. I don't understand what a content-type error is, so if someone could help me understand that would be great. Here's the code I have right now.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    const accountSid = 'AC5ca0acd115283b6d7ed38279';
    const authToken = 'not my real auth token';
    const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

    client.calls
          .create({
             to: '+14805402416',
             from: '+18448345500',
             record: 'True',
             transcribe: 'True',
             sendDigits: 'wwww1wwww123#wwww1', // w's are .5 second delays to navigate pauses in the automated system 
                                               // '1' - English, '123#' - PIN #, '1' - Confirm PIN
           });

    callback(null, client);
};
```

Comment: Where is your url or in-line twiml? The command  is missing key values.

Comment: I wasn't sure if they needed to be included or not. I am a little confused about the url and in-line twiml. I don't understand why one or both of those are needed to make an outgoing call like this. Perhaps one reason is Twilio doesn't know when to hang up? I've been combing through the docs and haven't found a description I could understand easily.

Comment: It tells Twilio what to do when the call is answered. You need one or the other, not both. The URL points to TwiML. Reference - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml.

Comment: Right, I get that the Twiml tells Twilio what do do when the call is answered. I think what confuses me is it seems the parameters in the create() call are also telling Twilio what do to? What are the advantages to using Twiml over the parameters?

Comment: Can you help me understand your use case, this way I can better answer your question, thanks.

Comment: Sure. I am trying to create an app that calls an automated phone system for information. The system is for a drug testing company for court-ordered drug testing. Currently, the only way to use thet system to manually call the company every day to find out if users are scheduled for a test. Our app would call the system automatically, record the conversation (bot-to-bot), and then send the user a transcribed SMS.

Comment: Ahh ok, so there are some parameters you can pass to the outbound-api call but TwiML (either via the URL parameter referring to TwiML or passing inline TwiML parameter  which is pretty new), will allow you to incorporate different TwiML verbs (Say/Play for Text to Speech or playing .mp3/.wav files), Gather to collect feedback via DTMF (Touch Tone) or Speech, and basically script out a automated interaction with the dialed party. Your bot-to-bot use case may not have such requirements but human-to-bot does.

Comment: Specific to transcribe, I don't see a transcribe attribute for the Calls Resource (the API call you are making), so you would need to use TwiML and the Record verb with the transcribe attribute to carry out that function, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#transcribe. Otherwise you would need to use an AddOn transcription partner - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133027-Transcribe-entire-phone-calls-with-Twilio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing either url or twiml in your construct.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource

> url
>   The absolute URL that returns the TwiML instructions for the call. We will call this URL using the method when the call connects. For more information, see the Url Parameter section in Making Calls.
>
> TwiML instructions for the call Twilio will use without fetching Twiml
>   from url parameter. If both twiml and url are provided then twiml
>   parameter will be ignored.